# Difference in count++ and count+1 in higher-order functions

Tags: javascript, variables, scope

> Example 1

```
function makeCounter() {
      let count = 0;

      return function() {
        return count++;
      };
    }

    let counter = makeCounter();

    alert( counter() ); 
    alert( counter() );
```

***Above alerts 0 and 1 respectively.***

---

> Example 2

```
function makeCounter() {
  let count = 0;

  return function() {
    return count+1;
  };
}

let counter = makeCounter();

alert( counter() ); 
alert( counter() );
```

***This alerts 1 and 1 respectively***

In programming count++ is equivalent to count+1 , then why is the difference in above two examples. I know its something related to closure property and hoisting. But understand perfectly. Could you guys help.

Note: Please let me know whether I should change the title of the question if it does not make sense.

Comment: `count++` is the same as `count = count + 1`.

Comment: @JosephWebber no it is not!  The value of  `(count = count + 1)` is 1 greater than the original value of `count`.

Comment: @Pointy sorry I updated the example 2 , it should have been count+1 instead of count++

Comment: @JosephWebber sorry I updated the example 2 , it should have been count+1 instead of count++

Comment: @Pointy My bad, you're right. It skipped my mind that the `++` would be done _after_ `count` was returned.

Comment: @YoYo  your assertion that "count++ is equivalent to count + 1" is simply wrong. They are definitely not equivalent expressions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The expression `count++` evaluates `count`, adds 1, stores the result in `count`, but the overall result (the net value of `count++`) is the **original** value of `count`.

The expression `count + 1` evaluates `count`, adds 1, and returns the result. The value of `count` is not changed.

Interestingly, while it's possible to mimic `++count` (pre-increment) with an alternative expression

```
var inc = (count += 1);
```

there's really no way (I can think of) to mimic `count++` cleanly without using a function, because there's no getting around the need for a temporary storage location:

```
var inc = () => { let tmp = count; count += 1; return tmp }();
```

The operator semantics of post-increment `++` dates from C in the 1970s and probably earlier, and has been copied by many other languages, including JavaScript. Folklore (as I remember it, being an old person) held that the pre- and post-increment operators were inspired by addressing modes available in the DEC PDP-11 instruction set, but that's always seemed fairly unlikely to me.

Comment: Hi Pointy thanks for your answer. Referring to your first statement, if it adds 1 and stores the result in count then how come the overall result returned is still 0 for the first alert?

Comment: @YoYo because that's how the post-increment operator works. It means that you want the *current* value of the variable (`count`), but after retrieving that you want the variable to be incremented. The value of `count++` is *defined in the language spec* to be the value of the variable *before* it is incremented.

Comment: @YoYo note that the PHP post-increment operator works exactly the same way.

Answer (score 3):

In your first example, you are post incrementing, i.e. adding 1 after the declaration and use. If you used ++count (pre incrementing) you would get 1 and 2 in your alerts.

In your second example, you do not store the value of count+1 back into count, so on the second time around, count is still 0 and you get the same result again.

Comment: Thanks Ajay for your answer, In first example , since it's a single statement, it should have incremented by 1 and then should have returned the incremented value. Why is this not happening?

Comment: @YoYo Although this is not exactly what is happening, this is the way that it was explained to me when I was starting out.
You are returning the increment itself, not the result of the increment.